# Where I can download java-x86-windows.dll

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I wanted to use **Java_Bridge** to use my java class in php file. But, for installing javabridge in my windows system i need **java-x86-windows.dll** which am unable to find. Where can i get this java-x86-windows.dll and is there any other method to call java functions form a php file?

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from this [site](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) or you may try on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=php-java-bridge-users&max_rows=25&style=nested&viewmonth=200611)

> The PHP/Java Bridge is an implementation of a streaming, XML-based
>   network protocol, which can be used to connect a native script engine,
>   for example PHP, Scheme or Python, with a Java virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Zend Server implementation of the Java/PHP bridge, I have used this in a production environment and its is very good. It doesn't require a Java server such as tomcat and provides a full PHP stack (apache, PHP and MySQL) reducing complexity (less moving parts). You can get here:

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/free-edition

Remember that you will have to add your jars to the Zend classpath in the watchdog-jb.ini file using the appropriate path delimiter for your OS (; for windows, and : for linux) and restart the server. You can then call your classes by:

```
$myClass = new Java("com.someclass", $data); //Your constructor
```

It is very similar to the sourceforge version from then onwards. Hope that helps.